# SharePoint 2013 Make Calculated Column based on Custom Column

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013, calculated-columns

In SharePoint 2013, I am trying to create a Calculated Column that is a shortened display of another Custom Column. The Calculated Column would just show the first 100 characters concatenated with "..." like in the following formula:

```
=LEFT([CustomColumn],100)&"..."
```

However, every time that I go to create this calculated column, SharePoint doesn't provide my [CustomColumn] in the "Insert Column:" list. If I type it in anyway, SharePoint throws an error.

Details on my Column, List, and Site below:

```
Col. Type: Multiple lines of text
Col. Group: Custom Columns
Col. Text Type: Enhanced rich text

List Content Type: Custom Type Inherits from Event

Site Type: Publishing
```

Also, to no avail, I found this [similar post](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/sharepoint/en-US/26a7517e-ba43-4c49-95aa-3e6f7f4207ba/calculated-field-in-content-type-not-working), but creating the Site Column and Calculated Column *before* adding it to the Content Type did not work for me.

Anyone out there know how to coax SharePoint into submission?!

Comment: I should mention that the company would prefer to use OOTB solutions as much as possible, if that becomes relevant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to this [forum response from a Microsoft representative](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/sharepoint/en-US/c73df850-8eb7-4b5c-8d97-4785daecb3b0/multiple-lines-of-text-fields-in-calculated-columns?forum=sharepointadminlegacy) *Multiple Lines of Text* columns cannot be used in *Calculated* columns.  The workaround that I always use for *Calculated* column limitations is to create a new field that will serve as your "fake" *Calculated* column (in your case probably a single line of text field) and then set the value using a workflow.  If you do not want users to be able to manually edit the "fake" *Calculated* column then hide it from the new/edit forms using the [SharePoint Manager 2013](http://spm.codeplex.com/).

Note - This method is also useful for doing *Calculated* columns that use *Lookup* columns.

Comment: Is there another way to make my "Multiple lines of text" field display in a shortened way? I'd prefer not to make my list's row very fat.